# GaussianNB: Get conditional probabilities

Tags: scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have GaussianNB Model

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
model = GaussianNB()
model=model.fit(x_train,y_train)
model.class_prior_  #get prior probabilities
```

How can I get the *conditional probabilities* (such as `P(Spam|Viagra=T + Sell=F)`) from the model?

Comment: Maybe using `predict_proba` like `probs = model.predict_proba(x_train)` can give you the posterior probabilities of each one of your training data points.

Comment: it gives me already the calcualted probabiliy. I would like to have conditional probabilities that the model uses.

Comment: I worry that you don't understand the Naive Bayes model. It never stores P(Spam | Viagra = T + Sell = F). It computes that on the fly from inverse probabilities, using Bayes's rule. So either you _do_ have to use `predict_proba`, or you have to calculate them yourself.

Comment: Ok, my question was just about if the model can return that probabilities from the data with which it was trained. Please move your comment to an answer so that I can accept it